# "SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value" when using MAX() in sub query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've checked as many questions as I could but just can't find an answer for WHY this happens.

I have a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA
WHERE Col1 = 
(
    SELECT MAX( TBC1 )
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY TBC2
)
```

which throws the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` but when I change the `=` operator to `IN` then it happily passes.  I also note that using `TOP(1)` in the sub query would also solve the issue.

From logic it looks like the fact that there is first a list of rows being returned before the `MAX` is found is causing the error in SQL even though `MAX` will only ever return 1 row?

I'm just trying to understand the reasoning and what's the best way to build such a query.

Comment: you are using group by in sub query. thats why it returns more than one value. Remove group by and check the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is as expected

You are grouping by TBC2. in that case Max(tb1) will return maximum value for each distinct value in tbc2.

Suppose tbc1 is employeeid, tbc2 as dept. If there are 100 records but it contain TBc2 having three types of values like dept1,dept2, dept3 then the query above will return 3 values.

Comment: Boy do I feel like a n00b right now.  I didn't take into account that `group by` would technically result in multiple rows even though I was filtering the results to a single row through a `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

You have a group by there. That query would return one row per distinct value of TBC2. Remove the group by.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `group by` is to enable aggregation over defined groups. Your `group by` causes return of a separate `max` (aggregate) for each distinct value of `TCB2`.

It seems like you might have added that `group by` without understanding what it does. Perhaps if you tell us what you're *trying* to do, we can show you how to do it correctly.